# Updating Checkboxes In NSTableView With A "Select All" Checkbox

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I've been searching, reading, trying different approaches, etc. for the last couple weeks trying to solve this issue, but no luck...  Any help is appreciated.

I have an NSTableView which uses my controller class as it's datasource, an NSMutableArray(validPropertyList) of NSDictionaries to be more exact.  I have the dictionaries holding one NSNumber numberWithBool with a key of @"checkboxValue", and one NSString with a key of @"address".  I initially set all the checkboxValues to YES.

```
        for (int i =0; i<properties.count; i++) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[properties objectAtIndex:i],@"address",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"checkboxValue", nil];

        [validPropertyList addObject:dict];
    }
```

My table has 2 columns, whose identifiers correspond to the key names of my dictionaries. 
In IB, I dragged over a Check Box Cell into the "checkboxValues" column.  The required methods are below for the table.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
return [validPropertyList count];
```

}

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
return  [[validPropertyList objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:identifier];
```

}

All of that works fine.  The table loads a (selected)checkbox in the first column and my string object in the other one for each dictionary in my array.

I implemented the below method in order to handle the state changes of the checkboxes in the table...

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[validPropertyList objectAtIndex:row]];
[dict setValue:object forKey:@"checkboxValue"];
[validPropertyList replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:dict];
```

//    NSLog(@"val is now %@",[[validPropertyList objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"checkboxValue"]);
}

This appears to work as well.  Clicking on a checkbox visually changes it's state.  It also updates the [NSNumber numberWithBool] value in my array as it should.

I have a checkbox outside of the table that I'm trying to use to either select all or deselect all of the checkboxes in the table.  I have a bool variable(selectAllValue) in my class that is bound to the state of this checkbox, and this checkbox calls the action below...

```
- (IBAction)selectAll:(id)sender {

if (selectAllValue == YES) {
    for (int i=0; i<[validPropertyList count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [validPropertyList objectAtIndex:i];
        [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"checkboxValue"];
        [validPropertyList replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dict];
    }
}
else{
    for (int i=0; i<[validPropertyList count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [validPropertyList objectAtIndex:i];
        [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"checkboxValue"];
        [validPropertyList replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dict];
          NSLog(@"new value in array when should be no is: %@",[validPropertyList objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}

[tv reloadData];
```

}

This does set all of the values in my array to the correct values, and then I call the [tv reloadData] to update the table.  It doesn't visually change the values of the checkboxes though. That's my problem.

I've tried adding checkboxes to my dictionary instead of NSNumbers, but no difference. I've tried binding the checkboxes in the table to the bool selectAllValue, but no difference.

I've read other posts on SO that relate to checkboxes in tables, but none of them really address this.  Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks
Scott

Comment: return 1; from -(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row method. is it working ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I can't return an int on that because its looking for an object.

Comment: if ([[[tableColumn headerCell] stringValue] compare:@"check_box"] == NSOrderedSame) return 1;

Comment: This looks ok, except you don't need to replace the object in the array each time, you're editing a mutable dictionary so the object in the array is done. Does `tv` definitely have a value when you call reloadData? If it was nil it could cause your issue. Otherwise, do the values in the checkboxes update when you scroll the table view?

Comment: Hey jrturton- tv was nil.  Thank you so much for that!  I set up the connection by control dragging to the header file in Xcode, but somehow it was not linked up.  Once again thanks!  I would have never thought of that.

Comment: @cottD were you able to solve this?